# Error when installing python package ml-insights

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, package

When I try to install `ml-insights` (referred to as `ml_insights` sometimes) using `pip install ml-insights` (https://pypi.org/project/ml-insights/), I get the following error (I use pyhton 3.8.5)

```
Collecting ml-insights
  Using cached ml_insights-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.0.0 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from ml-insights) (3.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.24.2 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from ml-insights) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.6.0 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from ml-insights) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from ml-insights) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.0 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from ml-insights) (1.22.3)
Collecting splinecalib>=0.0.2
  Using cached splinecalib-0.0.3.tar.gz (56 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->ml-insights) (3.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->ml-insights) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->ml-insights) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->ml-insights) (9.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->ml-insights) (4.33.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->ml-insights) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->ml-insights) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->ml-insights) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.24.2->ml-insights) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.24.2->ml-insights) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\micha\documents\odsp\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib>=2.0.0->ml-insights) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: splinecalib
  Building wheel for splinecalib (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for splinecalib (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for splinecalib
Failed to build splinecalib
Installing collected packages: splinecalib, ml-insights
  Running setup.py install for splinecalib: started
  Running setup.py install for splinecalib: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [14 lines of output]
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\splinecalib
  copying splinecalib\calib_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\splinecalib
  copying splinecalib\splinecalib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\splinecalib
  copying splinecalib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\splinecalib
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
  
  running build_ext
  building 'loss_fun_c' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for splinecalib
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Running setup.py install for splinecalib did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [16 lines of output]
  running install
  C:\Users\micha\Documents\Odsp\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
    warnings.warn(
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\splinecalib
  copying splinecalib\calib_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\splinecalib
  copying splinecalib\splinecalib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\splinecalib
  copying splinecalib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\splinecalib
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
  
  running build_ext
  building 'loss_fun_c' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Encountered error while trying to install package.

splinecalib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Comment: This should be resolved now with the latest version of ml_insights released last week